# In which direction would a single atom go if it absorbed heat through radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation

if a single atom with an absolute zero temperature was suspended in space, and it then received energy through radiation from a nearby object:

if that atom was in a lattice, it would vibrate, but since it's just a single atom, what would happen to it's kinetic energy? 
in which direction would that atom move ?

is it relative to the position of the radiating object 
or maybe to the frequency and amplitude of the radiation ?

Comment: Photon energy $E= h \nu$, momentum is $p = E/c$ in the direction the photon moves. Conserve momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of movement can only be affected by the relative position of the radiating source. Thinking about conservation of momentum, the atom must require a momentum that is in the direction of movement of the absorbed radiation, namely radially away from the emitting source (assuming a point particle or spherical emitter).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, so it's like it's "wants" to run away from the energy source,  but now that it had acquired the momentum, would his temperature be considered "absolute zero" ? since the radiating energy was already translated into kinetic energy.    (and assuming that the emitting object stopped emitting)

Comment: @physicsnewbie The temperature of a single atom is a poorly defined concept. You can try to define it as a quantity proportional to its velocity. This then already answers your question. But this temperature would be something very different than what we usually mean. Because any co-moving observer would see the temperature to be zero.